# Recursively get child objects

Tags: c#

I have a Class that can have Objects of the same type as children.

```
public partial class Page
{
    public Page StaticPage { get; set; }
}
```

So A Page can have a  StaticPage of type Page, which again can also have a further StaticPage of type Page. And so on.

What I need is a function that will return a List of all the Pages until the StaticPage is finally null.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman i was trying to keep it simple, I don't think anything I had tried was going to help anyone.

Comment: I firmly disagree with the close reason. There's nothing "too broad" here. An argument could be made for "unclear". Yes the downvotes are deserved due to the post being "I need a function that does X please make that for me", but the question is on topic.

Comment: The whole point of this is to broadly ask a relevant question that may help others solve a similar problem. All the questions/answers & examples that I have seen that look sort of related, are very specific.

Comment: @Monty - Try adding `public IEnumerable<Page> DescendantStaticPages() => this.StaticPage == null ? Enumerable.Empty<Page>() : this.StaticPage.DescendantStaticPages().StartWith(this.StaticPage);` to your `Page` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if the `StaticPage` property *could* be a null value, you should change its type to `Page?` to instruct the compiler that it could be null. See "Nullable Reference Types" for more details.

---

A simple `while` loop can be used here. Construct an in-memory list within the function, and each loop go deeper down.

```
List<Page> Foo(Page page)
{
    Page? currentPage = page;
    List<Page> pages = [];
    while (currentPage is not null)
    {
        pages.Add(currentPage);
        currentPage = currentPage.StaticPage;
    }
    return pages;
}
```

If you don't strictly need to return a `List<Page>` but can instead return an `IEnumerable<Page>`, removing the need for an in-memory list and using `yield return`.

```
static IEnumerable<Page> Foo(Page page)
{
    Page? currentPage = page;
    while (currentPage is not null)
    {
        yield return currentPage;
        currentPage = currentPage.StaticPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I wanted to avoid a while loop but your second solution is perfect, was exactly what I was hoping for. Gives me some insight into using yield return.

Comment: Why did you want to avoid a while loop? Any solution would have used one in one form or another.

Comment: This obviously met OP's requirements, so no real adjustment per their needs. However, there is a bug here if a static page points to a previously seen parent page, e.g., PageA -> PageB -> PageA. This will cause an endless while loop.

Comment: @GenericUser Yeah i have to figure out a solution for that.

Comment: @gunr2171 I wanted to avoid the 'simple while loop'. Never used yield before and this is about as simple example as you could get.