# Recursively return a List of Lists C#

Tags: c#

So I have a Class called Page. Each Page can have a List of Children (also Pages) which themselves can have further Lists of Children.

```
public partial class Page : POSCommand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Page>();
}
```

My task is to return a List of Lists of all the Children from all the Pages.

Here is what I have tried so far, but while modifying my code, it just goes into an endless loop now.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Page>> GetPages(Page page)
{
    Page? currentPage = page;
    while (currentPage.Children.Count() != 0)
    {
        yield return currentPage.Children.ToList();
        foreach (var pge in currentPage.Children)
        {
            yield return pge.Children.ToList();
        }
        currentPage = currentPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentPage = currentPage;` you keep processing the same page over and over and over. I don't understand what the return type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Page>>` represents. In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77715177) it was a flat list, a "list of a list" doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have changed my approach and now each page can have a list of Child Pages that in turn can have further list of Child Pages, and so on to infinity, however there is a practical limit to the depth, maybe only ever 1 or 2. 

The return is simply a list of all the lists of children (by page). 

I sort of had it working, but as you rightly pointed out, I'm processing the same page over and over. That's the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: This approach will easily suffer from a wrongly set relationship - `A->B->A` or the chain could be much longer but at some point very later it loops back, then the recursion stucks. Because you need to build the page relationship tree first, why not also at there populate this every-page collection? So it becomes pre-populated at very beginning, instead of looping everytime you need this collection.

Comment: a linq [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-8.0) might be far cheaper option than cooking your own loops..

Comment: @teamol Yes, the A->B->A issue. EF Core has the ability to autonomously track the Parent of each Child and populate a Property in Page (not shown here) using a Link Table..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65946177/ef-core-5-many-to-many-relationship-to-the-same-table 

I'm thinking that can be use to prevent circular reference, but that's another issue.

Comment: Circular references can be handled by using a hash set to track already visited entries. Basically, check if the content has been added to a hash set. If not then do your processing and then add it to the hash set. This way if you encounter the same entry again, you can automatically skip processing.

Comment: As a side note, the title of this post mentions recursion but the implementation is iterative.

Comment: So you just want the childrenschildren instead of infinite depth? Otherwise a `List<List<Page>>` doesn't make sense.  You class also lacks an identifier, it's basically just a collection wrapper.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter So I excluded other properties that I thought were not relevant to keep things nice and simple however, there is an Id and Guid Properties. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution can be done with a hash set. Already visited instances are tracked and once the method ends, the hash set is garbage collected. Ideally there would be some identifier so we could cache just that instead of the entire object.

**Updated based on edits to question**

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Page> GetPages(Page page, List<Page>? pageList = null, HashSet<int>? visited = null)
{
    pageList ??= [ page ];
    visited ??= [ page.Id ];

    if (page.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        return pageList;
    }

    foreach (var child in page.Children)
    {
        if (!visited.Contains(child.Id))
        {
            visited.Add(child.Id);
            pageList.Add(child);
            GetPages(child, pageList, visited);
        }
    }

    return pageList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "visited" flag that get toggles as you visit each node. This will prevent re-entrancy:

```
public partial class Page : POSCommand
{

    public bool visited = false;

    public ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Page>();

    static IEnumerable<Page> GetPages(Page page)
    {
        foreach (Page p1 in page.Children)
        {
            if (!p1.visited)
            {
                p1.visited = true;
                yield return p1;
                foreach (Page p2 in GetPages(p1))
                {
                    yield return p2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Just don't forget to write another help method that resets all those flags back to false when you're done.